# Show traffic between web service and client

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have simple Jersey based web service running on TomCat 9. I do development in Eclipse IDE. Server and IDE are on the same windows machine. I'm using Postman utility to generate test requests.

I would like somehow to see all request/response traffic between service and postman. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Using a traffic analyzer like `wireshark` will help on that.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz What if the traffic is SSL encrypted ? You'll fall in another problem (solvable maybe, but not ideal)

Comment: It's a local server so you have the private key for encryption, that would make decryption feasible with `wireshark`, a nice security workout.

Comment: [Jersey REST server and client troubleshooting](https://blog.jakubholy.net/2012/01/31/troubleshooting-jersey-rest-server-and-client/).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz you're just giving yourself more work with wireshark when compared to other solutions. +1 for the tuto you posted.

Comment: @EugèneAdell sometimes is not about work but about learning. `wireshark` is a powerful, non-intrusive analysis tool and for basic troubleshooting, is not hard to learn. Worth the effort in my opinion :)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I'm a contributor (small) of wireshark. Indeed you can use it for basic troubleshooting, but also for hard troubleshooting if you know how to use it with its advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

Postman will show you everything sent and received in the request (url, headers and content), but you can use a tool like Fiddler to view intercepted HTTP requests.

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I would like to see data that was sent in Postman. I'm expecting something like text box which contains everything - starting with request string and continuing cookies. But I can't find such information in one place.

Comment: Like Mr. Pablo Gazmuri said, you can see the http request data with a proxy such as Fiddler, Burp or OWASP Zap

Answer (score 0):

The *best way* is to use Tomcat's [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter). It's the *best* in the sense you don't need anything more than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on a eclipse integration you could use `burp`( https://portswigger.net/burp ).

In proxymode you can play "man in the middle" at your localhost and get every content.
You have just to setup burp as your proxy and you are done. You are also able to stop traffic etc. etc. This works for all kind of network traffic.

The tool is also available in a community edition.